# What is a more Scala way of writing this code?

Tags: scala, optimization, functional-programming

I want to strip off the word "America/" from the start of each item in the list, and the code below does just that, but I feel like it can be done in a significantly better way.

```
var tz = java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs
for(i <- 0 until tz.length) {
    if(tz(i).startsWith("America/")) {
        tz(i) = tz(i).replaceFirst("America/", "")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple and straight forward:

```
val tz = java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs.map(_.replaceFirst("^America/", ""))
```

Comment: Technically, you need a `^` in order to ensure the "America/" is at the start of the string like the original code checks, but for this particular data set it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

very similar to @Noah's answer, but using a for-yield iteration (so that you can add other filters with no more usage of parentheses).

```
import java.util.TimeZone
val tz = for(t <- TimeZone.getAvailableIDs) yield t.replaceFirst("^America/", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

I will use regex for it:

```
val pattern = "^America/".r
tz = tz.map(pattern.replaceFirstIn(_, ""))
```

wonder if it is an effcient way.

Answer (score 0):

Map is preferred to for loops in functional programming, so instead of changing the list in place with a for loop, passing the data around by mapping is more pure and (IMO) prettier.

Comment: Except... Scala doesn't have a for *loop*, it has a for *comprehension*.  Comprehensions are **very** functional, so much so that they're a core feature of Haskell.

Answer (score 0):

this can work:

```
val tzs = java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs map { tz =>
  if(tz.startsWith("America/")) tz.replaceFirst("America/","")
  else tz
}
```

Comment: The conditional is unnecessary, since `replaceAll` will return the `String` if there is no match. This is equivalent to `java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs map (_ replaceFirst ("America/", ""))`.

Comment: @ChrisMartin a `tz` may not starts with `"America/"`, but still contains it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread the intent. I think it'd be simpler to change the regex from "America/" to "^America/", though.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the American time zones, you could do this:

```
val americanZones = {
  val pattern = "^America/(.*)".r
  ( java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs
    flatMap pattern.findFirstMatchIn
    map (_ group 1) )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added an 'if' to the for/yield

```
val zones = java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs
val formatted_zones = for(i <- 0 until zones.length if zones(i).startsWith("America/")) yield {
  zones(i).replaceFirst("America/", "")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No regex:

```
val tz = java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs.map(_ stripPrefix "America/")
```